# HTML page jump with anchor not working

Tags: html, css, anchor

I've got a really simple problem that I'm sure there is a simple fix for, but I just can't find it.

I'm trying to jump from one page to another using an anchor, in order to load the new page on a particular div. Obviously this doesn't work, instead the page just loads at the top.

This is what my `<a>` tag looks like:

```
<a href="projects.html#link" onclick="location.reload()" class="col-sm-4 
noHighlight">
```

Then, on the page "projects.html" I have this:

```
<div class="container" id="link" name="link">
<br>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Test</h2>
<br>
<h5>
</h>
</div>
```

If, when the projects.html page has loaded, I force refresh my chrome browser tab, the page does load at the correct div. If I then scroll back to the top and force refresh the tab one more time, it doesn't work. The `location.reload()` was an attempt to force the browser to force refresh by itself, but nothing appears to change with or without it.

Any advice would be appreciated, If I need to post more code I will, but I don't really have much javascript or CSS that could be conflicting.

Thanks,

your boi, Boi.

Comment: Pretty sure it's because the page reload returns you to your scroll spot at the time you refreshed. I can't say for certain but I'd assume for the page jump to work it must be in a link or entered into the address bar

Comment: So I took the page reload code out, and annoyingly the same problem persists.

Comment: Yeah thats not what I meant, I think if you scroll and refresh it will always return you where you scrolled. Although you could make the data available so you could programmatically scroll to that spot after the reload, it seems like overkill to try to override a feature that is built into browsers as a convenience for users. When refreshing a page they expect it to be in the same spot they left it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your child theme CSS: html {scroll-behavior: auto !important;}